# Laravel Query Builder - Remove or Modify a Join

Tags: laravel

I have a Builder object that contains a `left` join that I want to conditionally make into an `inner` join. How do I remove or modify the existing join?

Comment: What about showing some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit ugly, but this works.

```
$query = App\User::leftJoin('tableX', 'tableX.user_id', 'users.id');

if ($some_condition) {
    foreach( $query->getQuery()->joins as $key => $join) {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause $join */
        if ($join->table == 'tableX') {
            unset($query->getQuery()->joins[$key]);
        }
    }
    $query->join('tableX', 'table.user_id', 'users.id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've accepted [Diogo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56068751/244826), but I also found that I can also edit an existing join. His solution shows how to retrieve the `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object from the `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object. I already have the Query Builder, so I wrote my function like this:

```
/**
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query
 * @param string $table
 * @param string $type
 */
private function changeJoinType(\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query, string $table, string $type): void
{
    foreach ($query->joins as $join) {
        if ($join->table === $table) {
            $join->type = $type;
        }
    }
}
```